# SQL query with user input

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I have an error

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended

when I try to execute the following SQL Statement.

In this statement, it is supposed to display all the rental details and feedback for a particular customer when a customer name is searched. "query" refers to the user input when the user searches for a name (CustomerName) in the database.

```
 SELECT c.CustomerName, r.Rental_ID, r.Staff_ID, r.RentalDate, r.DueDate,
 r.Customer_ID, f.Description 
 FROM Rental r, Customer c, FeedBack f 
 WHERE f.Customer_ID = r.Customer_ID 
 AND c.Customer_ID = f.Customer_ID 
 ORDER BY DueDate 
 WHERE CustomerName like "+ query +";
```

What went wrong?

Comment: i hope you are not literally appending the user provided name into your query and are instead using `PreparedStatements` so as to avoid the glaring sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @E.Wong your ORDER BY should come after the where clause change those places and check..

Comment: Hmm, yea, I do have prepared statement, just not included in my question. Haha. xD

Ah, I see, will do so and try it out. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Cause you have the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses in wrong places; not only that you actually have two `WHERE` clause in your query. It should be only one. `WHERE` should come first and then `order by`. It should rather be

```
WHERE CustomerName like "+ query +"
ORDER BY DueDate;
```

Also as a side note,

1. Consider using parameterized queries
2. Modify your query to use ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax instead old style syntax.

Your query should look like

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, r.Rental_ID, 
r.Staff_ID, r.RentalDate, 
r.DueDate, r.Customer_ID, f.Description
FROM Rental r  
JOIN FeedBack f ON f.Customer_ID = r.Customer_ID
JOIN Customer c ON c.Customer_ID = f.Customer_ID
WHERE c.CustomerName like "+ query +"
ORDER BY r.DueDate;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. My tutor taught me the old style syntax so I used that, but thanks for explaining. :)